# QT QAbstractTableModel implement insertRows

Tags: c++, qt, qabstracttablemodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have an Impl of QAbstractTableModel, which has a `vector<Item> items` with all items of the table (one Item per Row)

```
int rowCount(..){ return items.size() }
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role){
   Item i = items.at(index.row()));
   switch(index.column()){
      case 0: return i.zero;
       (..)
   }
}
```

Now I try to implement an `add_row(Item i)` Method:

```
void add_row(Item i){

   int row = rowCount(QModelIndex())+1;
   beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);

   items.push_back(i);

   endInsertRows();
   emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex());
}
```

The QAbstractTableModel is instanciated in my widget:

```
MyQSortFilterProxyModel my_filter = new MyQSortFilterProxyModel();
MyTableModel* my_model = new MyTableModel(items, this);
my_filter->setSourceModel(my_model);
ui->my_table->setModel(my_filter);
```

and I like to add a new row like that:

```
my_model->add_item(item);
ui->my_table->reset();
```

This almost works fine with just one problem. The item is added to my table at the correct position and shows up correctly, but the last row always disappears.
Where am I doing something wrong? Why does the last row always disappear?!

Thanks!

Update:

```
 void add_row(Item i){
  int row = rowCount(QModelIndex())+1;
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
  items.push_back(i);

  endInsertRows();
  emit dataChanged(createIndex(0,0), createIndex(row,5));
}
```

this works but always returns the following error:
`QSortFilterProxyModel: invalid inserted rows reported by source model`
Without the FilterProxyModel everything works find. What am I missing in the FilterProxyModel?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem or not, but I don't believe you can use empty QModelIndex values for the dataChanged signal. Try emitting the correct indexes for the beginning row that changed through the last row and covering all columns.

Comment: 1 - inserting rows does not change data, 2 - your row should be the count of items, not the row of a default constructed model index.

Comment: @goug I changed dataChanged to `dataChanged(createIndex(0,0), createIndex(row+1,columnCount)` it seems to work but it does take really long for the view to get updated (because I update everything?) but how can I get the index for the new row? (I am using a filter, so the index does not match)

Comment: @dtech what do you mean with 'your row should be the count of items'? the int row is the actual number of rows in my table.

Comment: Did you try to use the real `MyTableModel` without `MyQSortFilterProxyModel` for your table view? Does it work?

Comment: @vahancho without it is working. good point. Maybe here is the mistake, I am calling add_item() of the table model and not insertRow (of the filter?). I like to insert a row with already known content (the Item) and not just some empty row and call setData then.

Comment: @Tobi, I understand. You might try to insert a row with `insertRow()` and add data to the newly inserted row using `setData()` function. Or, call `items.push_back(i);` and than `insertRow()`.

Comment: I don't want to implement `setData`, my Item keeps more information than showen in the Table.  But I cannot call `items.push_back` in the filter, because the filter does not keep this vector and does not know anything about my table model impl

Comment: `int row =... ` in `add_row` is wrong. It should be `int row = rowCount(QModelIndex())`. If row count is 5 (from row 0 to 4), then the new row should be inserted to row 5, not 6.